# How do I gracefully handle missing arguments in a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The `missingMethod` method/hook is genius in the way it performs a catchall for Laravel controllers, but is this an equal method for missing method arguments?

I would like the equal of:

```
public function missingMethod($parameters) {
    echo "Missing!";
}

// but for arguments
public function missingArguments($parameters) {
    echo "Missing arguments!";
}
```

Instead I receive something similar to:

[image]

Comment: There is no such feature in Laravel.

Comment: Ok there is no built in feature.. but is there a way to handle it gracefully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ? in the route which will make it optional '/example/{id?}' the in your method give the parameters defaults i.e. ($id = null) then just check for null

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is actually a route - disguised as a 'missing method/argument'.

i.e.

If you have route  `/example/1`

your controller function is

```
public function show($id)
{
      echo $id;
}
```

So a "missing arguement" your controller function would be

```
public function missing()
{
    echo 'you need an id';
}
```

and your url is

```
/example
```

and your routes are

```
Route::get('/example/{id}', ['as' => 'example.show', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@show']);
Route::get('/example', ['as' => 'example.missing', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@missing']);
```